# What would make Internet Explorer NOT process conditional comments properly?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I'm writing JSP pages and using Tomcat, and it needs to work for IE 7 in addition to Firefox and Chrome (client needs).

In my program, I include both pieces of code.  It works properly for non-IE browsers.

My problem is that CODE A does not work properly for IE, in that it treats it like a comment rather than a conditional comment that it should be reading.  Any idea why this would happen and how to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 ...

 <!-- CODE A -->
 <!--[if IE]>
   url = "http://" + "..." + "&var=1";
 <![endif]-->

 <!-- CODE B -->
 <!--[if !IE]> -->
   url = "http://" + "..." + "&amp;var=1";
 <!-- <![endif]-->

 ...

</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use conditional comments inside JavaScript. Have you tried wrapping everything into separate `<script>` tags?

Comment: write your script once, and write it so that it works. Browser checking is A Bad Idea™.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional HTML comments only work in HTML. JavaScript is not HTML. Rather use conditional JS comments in JS:

```
var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
```

*(only IE will interpret the `!` which effectively makes it `true`)*

Then you can use it as follows

```
if (IE) {
    url = "http://" + "..." + "&var=1";
} else {
    url = "http://" + "..." + "&amp;var=1";
}
```

Feature detection should however be preferred in JS.

Comment: Your solution makes it work for IE but breaks it for Firefox. Firefox breaks on the line: 
`url = "http://" + "..." + "&var=1";`

Comment: That's a different problem. You've a syntax error somewhere along those lines. Read the error message.